# Making operations with TextField values

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to make operations with the values that the user enters in the two existent TextFields after hitting the button 'Calculate'. For example, if the user types 'Az' in the first and 'Dk' in the second, after hitting 'Calculate', it should print 'ADzk' (first letter of first input with the first letter of the second input and the same thing with the second letter). I'm having trouble with both retrieving the user's input and accessing the index of the values to manipulate how they will be printed. I'm really stuck.

```
class _TelaPrincipalState extends State<TelaPrincipal> {
  final firstTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final secondTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'App name example',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Merienda',
              fontSize: 23.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(120.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: firstTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Insert first input',
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: secondTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Insert second input',
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 55,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 18)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Calculate'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this logic

```
String data = "";

for (int i = 0; i < firstTextEditingController.text.length || i < secondTextEditingController.text.length; i++) {
 if (i < firstTextEditingController.text.length) data += firstTextEditingController.text[i];

 if (i < secondTextEditingController.text.length) data += secondTextEditingController.text[i];
```

}

Comment: Hey @Ankit Gada, thank you for your solution! I just don't know where I should put this logic inside the code, could you give me a hand?

Comment: On Click of any button and show the value in text widget.